# Divide an array into two sub arrays such that their sums are equal and possibly maximum

Tags: dynamic-programming, partitions, backtracking

Given an array A, we should partition A into two subarrays whose sums are equal, and that maximizes this sum.  We are free to omit items from the subarrays.

For example, `[7,2,5,7,12]` can be divided as the following:

1. `[5,2][7] = 7`
2. `[5,7][12] = 12`
3. `[7,7][2,12] = 14`

We need the final answer as `14` because the max possible sum is `14`.

I initially tried to generate all possible combinations of from length `1` to `N` and compare the sums and take intersection between two subsets. But it takes `pow(2,N)` time.

Is there an efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Please help how to approach this problem. I have tried state space tree with recursion like in the problem `subset_sum`. But couldn't solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard, by a straightforward reduction from [the partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).  Therefore, you should not expect any efficient algorithm.  However, there is a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm using dynamic programming (see [pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm for the partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm) for inspiration).